# AFNetworking.h file not found When project remove another mac

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am using `AFNetworking` via `Cocoapods`. Here is the version of the AFNetworking :

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
```

The project currently runs on my working Mac. 
But when I move to project on another Mac I see this error.

> AFNetworking.h file not found error

in `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h` class.

Comment: Have you tried to run `pod install` in the other mac?

Comment: Yes I have install pod in other mac

Comment: Try this: `pod 'AFNetworking', '2.0'`

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 2):

Remove the followings .

**Pods folder , Podfile.lock , Projectname.xcworkspace**

write

```
 pod 'AFNetworking', '2.0'
```

instead of

```
 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
```

in your podfile .

then install the pod again .